# How to convert list of dictionaries to dictionary in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list like below:

```
[{"id":0,"test":null,"number":0,"range":111028}, 
 {"id":2,"test":null,"number":0,"range":110931}, 
 {"id":3,"test":null,"number":0,"range":64222}]
```

How can I convert it to a dictionary in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can use :

```
for i in range(len(list)):
   dict1 = list[i]
```